# MyGet - Force nuget push to push latest package

Tags: nuget, myget

We have been using MyGet for the past couple weeks and we noticed that when we use the `nuget push` command to add a new nuget package to our feed it doesn't automatically get flagged as latest package. It seems like they are being ordered alphabetically.

Is there any way to tell MyGet that I have just pushed the the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

What is the current latest version on the feed for that package, and what version are you pushing and expecting to appear as "latest"? Sorting is by version (see also https://semver.org for versioning guidance)

Comment: same question I had...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158868/why-is-the-wrong-version-in-a-myget-feed-labelled-as-the-latest-version-of-the-p

Anyone can explain this?