# Why is the wrong version in a MyGet feed labelled as the latest version of the package?

Tags: myget

There are several versions created for [MyGet : System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.myget.org/feed/system-linq-dynamic-core/package/nuget/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) :

[image: MyGet]

However for some reason the oldest version still has the flag `latest` ?
Is this a bug in MyGet, or is there a setting to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I have found that it is not the issue with myget flagging the latest packages, it is to do with NuGet package versioning rules.

Please read this link to understand your issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning

For me, the issue was as follows,

The packages were versioned like,

7.2.0.build999    - This was flagged latest 
7.2.0.build1000   - This was not flagged latest even uploaded after 999 and versioned higher than 999

And the reason was,

> When resolving package references and multiple package versions differ
>   only by suffix, NuGet chooses a version without a suffix first, then
>   applies precedence to pre-release versions in reverse alphabetical
>   order.

Hope this helps :)